Splunk query to get the host name where no api hits in last 24 hours
Working on a splunk query to get the list of hostnames where no api call hit from past 24 hours in order to determine the server is working or
Decommissioned
Some one send if you have handy
Trying to check for the server which is not working

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
